# why does the subsurface modifier create such a harsh edge here

Tags: subdivision-surface

I have tried various fixes like removing doubles, altering the mesh, the problem persists.
Here's the .blend:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OwhsqAuXHCTySSfbciQxV9f1igz4xLQ1

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a problem of normals, select all and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate and it will fix it.

Comment: I don't know why it's not visible though, I'm not very familiar with 2.8 yet    ;)

Answer (score 0):

I’m quite sure it’s because you have seven edges converging into one vertex.

From what I understand, the Subsurf Modifier is approximating vertex *relationships* not the vertexes themselves i.e. it will not move that vertex to round things off because it is rounding the space/edges between vertexes.

To have a stray vertex will definitely cause issues like this especially when tris/multiple edges are involved.

Solution: Fix the topology. Maybe use a knife tool or go in and delete some data? Basically, you should almost never have seven edges going into one vertex like that. Addressing that will probably fix your issue.

John